# What is the formula for getting the most contrasting color for the specified color?

Tags: colors, contrast, high-contrast

I write an application where there is a need to get second color having big contrast from the input color. So the contrast between 2  colors must be more than or equal to 7. Does anyone know a working formula? I have found some questions about this topic, but none of the answers is working for me.

Comment: What do you mean for "contrast"? Usually we intend just brightness, so use black or white according how bright was the specified colour. If you care less about "most", but just "good", you can choose also "opposite hue"

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi by telling "contrast" I mean color contrast ratio(https://medium.muz.li/the-science-of-color-contrast-an-expert-designers-guide-33e84c41d156#:~:text=Calculating%20a%20Contrast%20Ratio,the%20darker%20of%20the%20colors.). I need to find appropriate pair color for having have color contrast ratio more than or equal to 7. And if you tell me to choose "opposite hue" what saturation and lightness shall I use with it?

Comment: The article use the formula *(L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05)* so it is all luminosity. Then you have a lot of choices, it is more a design/artistic choice (and what are you doing). Background with text? I would keep one (possibly background) with low saturation. A logo? You can be more bold. Various colours? Try to get a meaning to the colour (easier to interpret for reader). Note: I prefer 120 degree other 180 (180 has sometime some disturbing combinations, yellow and blue together tend to create extra illusions)

Answer (score 1):

I asked Bard AI, while its anwsers don't work for gray colors like `rgb(127,127,127)`, so I revised one of the anwsers, here is it:

```js
/**
 * get contrast color in monochrome
 * @param {Array<number>} rgb - rgb channels, 0~255
 * @param {number} maxContrast 128~255
 * @returns {Array<number>}
 */
function getContrastColor([r, g, b], maxContrast = 192) {
  const minContrast = 128;
  let y = Math.round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b); // luma
  let oy = 255 - y; // opposite
  let dy = oy - y; // delta
  if (Math.abs(dy) > maxContrast) {
    dy = Math.sign(dy) * maxContrast;
    oy = y + dy;
  } else if (Math.abs(dy) < minContrast) {
    dy = Math.sign(dy) * minContrast;
    oy = y + dy;
  }
  return [oy, oy, oy];
}
```

And some test results:

```js
getContrastColor([0,0,0]) // [192, 192, 192]
getContrastColor([255,0,0]) // [204, 204, 204]
getContrastColor([127,127,127]) // [255, 255, 255]
getContrastColor([128,128,128]) // [0, 0, 0]
getContrastColor([255,255,0]) // [34, 34, 34]
getContrastColor([255,255,255]) // [63, 63, 63]
```

You may set maxContrast to 255 as needed.